# Run 3 jobs sequantially

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am newbie to shell. I am trying to run 3 jobs sequentially. But I am not sure where I am going wrong. The jobs are not running in sequence. Please help on this.

```
Job 1
Job 2
Job 3
```

Here is the script to run the jobs:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
{
sync;
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

/data/Job1.sh

if [ `ps -ef | egrep 'awk' | egrep -v egrep | wc -l` -gt 1 ]]


    /data/Job2.sh

if [[ `ps -ef | egrep 'awk' | egrep -v egrep | wc -l` -gt 1 ]];

    /data/Job3.sh

fi
}
```

UPDATE:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 ]; then
        NUM_PROC=$1
else
        NUM_PROC=10
fi

for i in `seq 0 $((NUM_PROC-1))`; do
        awk 'BEGIN {for(i=0;i<10000;i++)for(j=0;j<10000;j++);}' &
done

echo "PIDS: `pidof awk`"

**Shell script running: **scripts/job.sh 5****
```

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they are putting to solve their own problems, kindly do add your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Comment: i have written the code. I am not sure what is the mistake in it.  I need to cleat the cache before i run each job and start the job after the previous job execution

Comment: @Pami, you have made a bunch of `if` and `elif`. Only one of them will run whichever is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `wait` if you want to use it as a child process. Otherwise, remove the `&` after `$job` and the entire line `wait $!` as commented in the example.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

JOB_ARRAY=("/data/Job1.sh" "/data/Job2.sh" "/data/Job3.sh")
for job in "${JOB_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    sync;
    echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;

    echo "Starting job $job"
    $job &  # remove `&`
    echo "Started job with pid $!"

    wait $! # remove entire line
    echo "Job finished, exit code is $?"
done
exit 0
```

EDIT:
In the `JobX.sh` scripts you'll have to wait until the child processes are finished. Append the following code to each `JobX.sh` script:

```sh
NUM_PROC=$1
[ ! -z "${NUM_PROC}" ] || NUM_PROC=10

for i in `seq 0 $((NUM_PROC-1))`; do
        awk 'BEGIN {for(i=0;i<10000;i++)for(j=0;j<10000;j++);}' &
done

echo "PIDS: `pidof awk`"

# Wait for every child process to finish
wait
exit $?
```

p.s. you should always end your scripts with `exit`. Always enclose variables with `""` if you use it in if, while, fir (etc) statements. And try to make functions instead of separate scripts:

```
#! /bin/bash
function _test_echo {
    local message=$1
    echo $message
}
_test_echo "Hello world!"
exit 0
```

Good luck scripting!

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the above script runs all jobs parallel. I need to check for a condition and then run the scripts sequentially

Comment: Nope, the code I’ve written executes a job after job n-1 has ended ;-) It might be the case that your job.sh does something wrong. Please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: I have to check for this condition before a jobs starts if [ `ps -ef | egrep 'awk' | egrep -v egrep | wc -l` -gt 1 ]]

Comment: I am stuck in this place. Where i need to check for a process before i start the job

Comment: You don't have to use `ps` because `wait $!` waits until the process with pid `$!` finishes. If you really want to use `ps`, try `ps -ef | egrep 'awk' | egrep -v awk` without `wc -l` first.

Comment: Wait is not working in my case `[root@Oracle-12c ~]# sh  test-2409-4.sh
Starting job sh job1.sh

PIDS: 93292 93291

Started job with pid

Job finished, exit code is 0

Starting job sh job2.sh

PIDS: 93300 93299 93298 93292 93291

Started job with pid

Job finished, exit code is 0

Starting job sh job3.sh

PIDS: 93310 93309 93307 93306 93300 93299 93298 93292 93291

Started job with pid`

Comment: You can see here that it does not wait for PID are repeating in this case for all the 3 jobs

Comment: It's strange that `$!` gives multiple pids. Can you update your question with the content of /data/Job1.sh, /data/Job2.sh and /data/Job3.sh?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199903/discussion-between-pami-and-bayou).